# Error running Iota MAM example

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging

I tried to run the MAM example from the git:
https://github.com/iotaledger/mam.client.js

Running the post.js from the /examples/ folder I got the following error:

```
/root/mam.client.js/lib/mam.js:102
bundle.addEntry(signatureFragments.length, address, value, tag, timestamp);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at new create (/root/mam.client.js/lib/mam.js:102:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/mam.client.js/examples/post.js:25:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Can anybody help with this?

Also see this [issue on Github](https://github.com/iotaledger/mam.client.js/issues/17).

Answer (score 1):

To try MAM I recommend using the instructions as per latest IOTA meetup in Amsterdam. You can download the source from http://iotameetup.nl/ and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZO2ysgzKkM @ 1:21:00 for more instructions. Worked fine for my getting started. Not sure if that matches the github repo.

Comment: Yeah I got started with those instructions and it worked fine. But now I wanted to dive a bit deeper and work with private and restricted messages. The Git Repo is very different from the code used in the meetup. I hope there will be some updates and tutrials to this soon... this is such a cool feature and it seems like it hasn't got any attention since release.

Comment: I'm assuming it will be updated once they release the data market API set.