# MAM Issue:TypeError: Transaction.quietFromHash is not a function

Tags: masked-authenticated-messaging, error, ixi

I am currently playing around with the MAM feature and installed the MAM.ixi extension on my node.
Unfortunately I ran into an error when trying to access the getMessage function:

> "Request Error: TypeError: Transaction.quietFromHash is not a function"

It's caused by the ixi extension, but I'm not really familiar with those extension and not sure if you could debug them. (https://github.com/iotaledger/MAM.ixi/blob/master/index.js, line 22).

I basically used the examples from the github: https://github.com/iotaledger/mam.client.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported the use of [mam.client.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/mam.client.js) is deprecated.

Try with the source from [http://iotameetup.nl](http://iotameetup.nl/) and watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ZO2ysgzKkM) @ 1:21:00 as already suggested by [this answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/1036/212).